# User Login History

Tags: joomla-3.x, login, security

This may have ben asked elsewhere however I couldn't see it on JSE.

Is it possible to view the user login history anywhere? I had a look through the database however couldn't find anything. Joomla 3.4.1

I am able to see that last login info, however it would be useful to see the same info for the last 10 (or more) logins for example.

I have found this extension [Logman](http://www.joomlatools.com/pricing/) which loks like it would do the trick, but was wondering if there is al alternative method of retrieving this info?

Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've personally been using [Saxum IP logger](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/saxum-iplogger) for a couple of years now. It's a great (FREE) extension that provides information such as:

- Number of logins for each user (date, IP, etc)
- Number of different IP addresses each user has used to login
- Ability to block IP's
- And other nice features

The first screenshot below is a snippet of all the users that have ever logged in on your site. If you click on a username from that list, it will show you all login instances of that user.

[image]

***Note:*** County and Cities used to work but doesn't appear to be now. Odd.

But either way, I'd recommend giving it a go.

Hope this helps

Comment: his looks perfect @Lodder - thanks! How have I not seen this before and why does it not come as standard! Either way, thanks.

Comment: @johnny_s - You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 4):

Joomla only stores the last login.  You'd have to write a very simple user plugin that writes the login event somewhere, which is what that plugin seems to do.

Answer (score 1):

As at Joomla 3.9.0, there is a new "User Actions Log" included in the Joomla core which tracks logins, extension updates and extension configuration updates, for example.

Remember to enable the appropriate user actions plugins for this to work.

[image: User Actions Log]